# How do I approach requesting a retainer?

Tags: payments, pay-rate, retainer

I was interviewed today for an ongoing support contract, I'm fairly new to freelancing and not come across this kind of work before.

I generally just quote per hour for the developement work I do but would like to take this opportunity to establish a regular income, some sort of retainer that I can rely on.

How does this kind of thing normally work, do I just quote x hours at my standard rate, use it or lose it, would a freelancer normally offer discounts on hours not worked, bit really sure how to broach the subject.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless the other party has different requirements, you should commit on the daily number of hours, warn in case you won't perform and of course not charge !

Answer (score 1):

What we have found that works is to estimate what you think will be the # of hours per week on average that you would be doing this work, multiply that by your desired rate and quote that as the monthly (x4 week) retainer.  Then put in wording in the contract that you and the client agree to do a review after 3 months to ensure that you are both getting value, which gives you the option to raise (or lower if you think it is warranted) the retainer amount, and this gives the client the option to opt-out if they so choose.